# How to acess pictures Xamarin.Forms,SQLite, C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

i am creating mobile application where user can post adverts with pictures and text. I am using Media.Plugin by James Montemagno. That works very well. Also the user should be able to tap on the picture to review and possibly delete. I am not sure how to access these pictures, i dont know where they are stored so even if i would want to delete them i am not sure how to access each picture. COuld you please help me? 
The user is able to take several images and then they are displayed on the main page. I would like the user to be able to review them once again and then if he continues with them to the second page he will upload some other data and on the third page it should all display together. How can i Display pictures on the third page?

```
public partial class AddingPage : ContentPage
    {
        AdLogEntry adLogEntry = new AdLogEntry();
        //CameraService cameraService = new CameraService();
        public byte[] imageAsBytes;
        public string pathLabel;
        private const int MaxColumns = 3;
        private int _currentRow = 0;
        private int _currentColumn = 0;


        public AddingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await MainProgressBar.ProgressTo(0, 250, Easing.Linear); ;
        }
        private async void NextStep_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Informations());
        }

        private async void TakePicture_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await TakePicture();

        }

private async Task TakePicture()
        {
            MediaFile file = null;

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Nemáme přístup", "Nelze nalézt kameru", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var imageSource = await DisplayActionSheet("Foto", "Cancel", null, new string[] { "Pořídit novou fotku", "Nahrát foto z galerie" });
            var photoName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

            switch (imageSource)
            {
                case "Pořídit novou fotku":
                    file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        SaveToAlbum = true,
                        Directory = "Photos",
                        Name = photoName
                    });
                    //Get the public album path
                    var aPpath = file.AlbumPath;

                    //Get private path
                    var path = file.Path;

                    break;

                case "Nahrát foto z galerie":
                    file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                    //Directory.GetFiles( "Photos");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (file == null)
                return;

            // Photo => Grid 
            _currentColumn++;

            if (_currentColumn > MaxColumns - 0)
            {
                _currentColumn++;
                _currentRow++;

                // Add a new row definition by copying the first row.
                ImageGridContainer.RowDefinitions.Add(ImageGridContainer.RowDefinitions[0]);
            }

            var newImage = new Image()
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                Scale = 0
            };

            ImageGridContainer.Children.Add(newImage, _currentColumn, _currentRow);

            await Task.Delay(250);

            await newImage.ScaleTo(1, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure how to access these pictures" - your code that you just posted is accessing the pictures using the MediaFile object returned by the media plugin.

Comment: You can get the AlbumPath, file.Path, that's the location where these pictures stored.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  Hi, ok, well how do i get that? The user is able to take several images and then they are displayed on the main page. I would like the user to be able to review them once again and then if he continues with them to the second page he will upload some other data and on the third page it should all display together.

Comment: User see those pictures in the control `newImage`, you can set the source of newImage to a null value to remove the picture in the  `newImage`.